# Why is the ring of algebraic integers denoted by $\mathcal O_K$?

Tags: mathematics, notation, abstract-algebra

Why/when was the curly-O notation chosen for the ring of integers of an algebraic number field $K$?

Comment: the ring of [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) can also be characterized as the maximal [Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(ring_theory)) of the field $K$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner why is it called order? I only know the analytic sense of the word (less than, greater than) and like the size of a group or subgroup generated by an element; this seems to fit neither

Comment: click on the word Order in my comment above to see the ring theory sense of the word

Comment: The term order comes from the biological classification system, which also includes other terms adopted by mathematicians: class, family, and genus (and species in combinatorics).

Comment: This has been answered already: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/who-first-introduced-the-notation-mathcalo-in-algebraic-geometry-or-algebra